# Best Practice question: Google App Scripts from Spreadsheet to Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets, google-docs

My basic problem is this.

I will be taking data from a Google Sheet that looks a LOT like this:

[image: Google Spreadsheet]

My current code is basically grabbing the selection turning it into a Range[], turning that into an object array, and going through that array row by row.

Here is the code:

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var ranger = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
var num = ranger.getNumRows()
var dataArray = ranger.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
```

From here, I open the Doc from Template and replace placeholder values with those procured above:

```
body.replaceText("##SONG NAME##", songname);
body.replaceText("##Artist##", artist);
```

Each ROW of data is a new copy of a Google Doc.

So, in superficial terms:
I grab all data. Put it into an object array. Then for each row of the array (which is a different song for our business), I open a new doc, replace the data. Rename, save and close the doc.

Cleanse, Repeat.

I could create a business case to APPEND data to the same document.

Thus grab all data, put into object array, then each row is a new appended SECTION of the same document. Once the for loop ends, we rename, save close...

And that leads to my question:

What are the server implications of what I'm doing? What are the performance hits?

If I want this to run as quickly and efficiently as possible should I change the way I'm collecting data? How I'm passing and replacing the data in the target doc? Should I append? Or is it not a big hit to create anew each time?

I'm just looking for knowledge about the code running optimally, please don't surmise about business or aesthetics.

Comment: Focus down to one question.

Comment: It really is one question. What's is the best practice for problems like this (taking structured data and passing it to a google doc template.)

Comment: It's a question that leads may lead to many opinions and as such is not a question that falls within our scope.  Read best practices in the documentation and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Totally fair. I was actually hoping for many opinions, but if that's not to scope I understand. I'm trying to learn the many schools of thought to help develop my own. I can read the documentation, and draw my own conclusions, but frankly there are smarter, more informed people than myself.